# Entity Framework 4 Entity with EntityState of Unchanged firing update

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF 4, mapping all CUD operations for my entities using sprocs.

I have two tables, ADDRESS and PERSON.  A PERSON can have multiple ADDRESS associated with them.

Here is the code I am running:

```
Person person = (from p in context.People
                             where p.PersonUID == 1
                             select p).FirstOrDefault();

Address address = (from a in context.Addresses
                               where a.AddressUID == 51
                               select a).FirstOrDefault();

address.AddressLn2 = "Test";

context.SaveChanges();
```

The Address being updated is associated with the Person I am retrieveing - although they are not explicitly linked in any way in the code.  When the context.SaveChanges() executes not only does the Update sproc for my Address entity get fired (like you would expect), but so does the Update sproc for the Person entity - even though you can see there was no change made to the Person entity.

When I check the EntityState of both objects before the context.SaveChanges() call I see that my Address entity has an EntityState of "Modified" and my Person enity has an EntityState of "Unchanged".

Why is the Update sproc being called for the Person entity?  Is there a setting of some sort that I can set to prevent this from happening?

---

I created a second project to make sure the issue was not happening because of something in my current project environment.

First, I created a new database that contains an Order and OrderDetail table.  They have a foreign key between them so that Order can have more than one OrderDetail associated with it.  I also created "after Update" DB triggers on the Order and OrderDetail tables that update a DateTime field when a record is updated.

Second, I created a simple WPF application and created a ADO.NET Entity Model that was generated from my database.

Third, I added code to my class constructor as follows:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      MyEntities context = new MyEntities();

      Order order = (from o in context.Orders
              select o).FirstOrDefault();

      OrderDetail orderDetail = (from d in order.OrderDetails
                    select d).FirstOrDefault();

      orderDetail.Qty = 7;

      context.SaveChanges();
    }
  }
```

I ran the program without doing any function mapping for my Order and OrderDetail objects.  The result was exactly what I would expect to see, the OrderDetail record is updated to have a Qty of 7 and the UpdateDateTime field is populated with the date and time the update occurred.  No changes to my the Order record which means no update occurred.

I then create stored procedures to handle the update of Order and OrderDetail tables in the DB.  They don't do anything special, just accept parameters for every column in the table and then set each field equal to the associated parameter.  I then mapped those stored procedures to my Model objects using the Mapping Details (Map Entity to Functions) window.

After doing the mapping, I ran the program.  As a result I observed the expected behavior of seeing updates to the OrderDetail table, but in addition the Order table "after Update" trigger had fired and the UdateDateTime field was set to the date and time the update occurred - which I would not expect.

Does anyone know of a way to utilize stored procedures for all Insert, Update and Delete operations and not have the updates cascade up to related entities?

Comment: Just to make sure, there is no other code associated with your error?

Comment: I am not seeing an error.  I am just not seeing the behavior I expect and I am wondering why and what I need to do in order to see the expected behavior, which would be that only the Address entity gets updated in the DB.

The only other code would be the instantiation of my context object which just creates a new instance of the EF generated entity context.

Comment: UPDATE: As I said in my original posting, I am using stored procedures to handle Create, Update and Deletes on all of my tables.  I just removed those mappings from my Model and ran the code again with a DB trigger on the Person table and NO UPDATE happened.  Looks like it is the sproc mappings for Create, Update and Delete which is causing the Update to happen in this case.  Unfortunately, we have to use sprocs for those operations so a resolution is still required.  I just thought I would update the posting with more information.

Comment: Is anyone else seeing this behavior?  It would be helpful to know that this is not just an issue with my setup.

Comment: I have reported this bug to Microsoft via Microsoft Connect. If you have seen the same behavior, please go to this item and indicate that you can reproduce the bug. [https://connect.microsoft.com/data/feedback/details/565160/mapping-update-function-to-stored-procedure-causing-cascading-updates](https://connect.microsoft.com/data/feedback/details/565160/mapping-update-function-to-stored-procedure-causing-cascading-updates)

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue, and it has been solved by the hotfix mentioned on [that MS KBD page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390624).

The fix was only published widely in .NET 4.5. However, I expect that EF 6 (which works both on .NET 4 / .NET 4.5) will also ship that fix, as it supersedes the version of System.Data.Entity.dll shipped with .NET 4 with its own.