# How can one prevent Entity Framework from calling the update stored procedure, even though nothing should have changed?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I have an entity A that has a link to an entity B through the property `prop`. The relationship is a 1-n relationship (foreign key in the table corresponding to A).

The relationship is bidirectional (B has a property that lists all A through which it is related with `prop`).

We have been able to determine that, in that case, the `saveChanges` method call was calling the `update` stored procedure for the B table, even though none of the columns in the table had changed.

Is that normal/expected? How should someone do to avoid it?

**Edit**: I have checked the state flags for both the "A" and "B" objects, and as expected, the "B" object is in the "unchanged" state.

**Edit 2**: Thanks to everyone for telling me about update flags (I didn't know how to access that information) - which has led me to find that link, describing my problem in more detail:

[Entity Framework 4 Entity with EntityState of Unchanged firing update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931628/entity-framework-4-entity-with-entitystate-of-unchanged-firing-update)

Comment: Nah, I don't buy it . . . check the "update flags" on the items in your context . . . I'm guessing you'll find that something has the change flag set . . . you need to figure out what caused the "change".

Comment: I agree with Frank. Something has changed.

Comment: @Frank, @DustinDavis: Just checked the state flags for both objects. The "A" object is in the modified, while the "B" object is in the state "unchanged".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hotfix mentioned on http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390624

Though that support issue's description is only loosely related to the behaviour I describe, the provided hotfix also solves my issue.

That issue has been publicly fixed on in release 4.5 of the .NET framework. For the .NET 4.0 framework, I would expect that using EF 6.0 (currently in beta) would also solve the issue.

Comment: Did you have to pay for the hot fix? The only avenues I am seeing to get it are by paying $100+ for support from MS. I need to get a hold of the hot fix, but doesn't feel right to have to pay for it.

Comment: I was able to get it through my company, and I think that was through an official support request.

Comment: They made us pay for an official support request as well. What a racket, given it is a known issue with the framework that they have refused to officially release for 2 years!