# Entity Framework SaveChanges is saving unchanged record (via stored procedure mapping)

Tags: entity-framework

I'm calling saveChanges on a context that has 2 entities attached. Entity 'A' receives updates to it's values, 'B' does not change.

When I pause the code on the line before SaveChanges, and inspect the 'B' entity and it says "EntityState = Unchanged(2)".

I let the code finish running and I end up with the Store Procedure that is mapped to the 'B' Entity's Update executing.

I expected that this would not happen, why is it?

Thanks
Gord

EF 4.0.30319

Comment: What version of Entity Framework? Somewhat of a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931628/entity-framework-4-entity-with-entitystate-of-unchanged-firing-update)

Comment: Entity Framework 4.0.30319

Comment: I believe this may be a known bug with that version which has since been corrected.  Backup your files, update to latest and see if you still have an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this question is a duplicate of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931628).

To repeat the answer given there:

That is an issue that happens when:

- Running Entity Framework on .NET Framework version 4.0;
- Using custom mapping SQL code;

The issue can be fixed in 1 of 3 ways:

- Get and deploy the hotfix from Microsoft described on [MS KB 2390624](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2390624) - that request requires paid assistance from Microsoft (e.g. through a company support contract);
- Upgrade to .NET 4.5 (only an option if you do not have to worry about Windows XP anymore);
- Upgrade to Entity Framework 6 (currently in beta, but I would expect it to not exhibit that bug);